# Chrome Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i have two spans on my page with class='hidden' and then some javascript to remove the class when a condition is met, its working fine in ie 9/10 and firefox but its not working in chrome when I run the function in the chrome JS console I get the message TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of null

Anybody know whats going on?

```
<script type='text/javascript' >
function showhidden()   {

        var att =document.getElementById('hiddentextbox');
        att.attributes[0].value='';
        att =document.getElementById('hiddentextbox1');
        att.attributes[0].value='';
}</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: This code does nothing what you describe it should do. Are you sure you pasted the right code?

Comment: yep it was the right code, att.attributes[0] creates an array of all the attributes inside the <span> tag so [0].value accesses the value of the 0th element if i used [0].name it would give me 'class' because i have <span id='hiddentextbox' class='hidden'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the class by using `att.className = ''` instead of what you're doing, which I have never seen before.

You might also want to check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which has good built-in `.show()` and `.hide()` functions.

Comment: yea that works thanks, serves me right for using obscure sites i suppose although its strange that it worked in ie and firefox, got it from here if your curious http://www.coursesweb.net/javascript/getelementbyid

Answer (score -1):

It can't find `document.getElementById('hiddentextbox');` therefore it can't find attributes of `null`, because non-found element is `null`. I believe that is the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if it says it's null, that means it doesn't exist.